# How can I associate file types with my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I need to implemet logic, when I open attached filed to mail it will be associated with my application. I have read information about it:

[Registering the File Types Your App Supports](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html)

[image]

But when i open .png file that I have attached in mail letter I don't see icon of my application.
How can I resolve it?

Comment: I guess these will help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017468/ios-document-file-type-associations-wildcard-uti

Comment: I have read this post too, and I use it like instruction, but it is not work for me