# How to register item provider for any type of information?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How to register item provider for any type of information?

I use app extensions.
How to register item provider for any type of information? Audio, video, PDF, anything?
I know that for know kind of type like PDF or audio this know type can be registered using `UTType` and code like:

```
let itemProvider = NSItemProvider()
itemProvider.registerItemForTypeIdentifier(kUTTypePDF as String) { completionHandler, expectedValueClass, options in
let data = try! NSData(contentsOfURL: fileURL, options: .DataReadingMappedAlways)
completionHandler(data, nil)
}
```

I can not find `UTType` for any information. I know there is `kUTTypeData` .The type identifier for any sort of simple byte stream, including files and in-memory data. But, looks like this `kUTTypeData` will not be for what I need.

Also link about `UTType`. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MobileCoreServices/Reference/UTTypeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/UTI_Text_Types

Maybe this code: https://gist.github.com/evadne/5519337 will help.

```
NSArray *allIdentifiers = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)UTTypeCreateAllIdentifiersForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, pathExtension, CFSTR("public.font"));
        if (![allIdentifiers count]) {
            return NO;
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Document/File type associations - wildcard UTI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017468/ios-document-file-type-associations-wildcard-uti)

Comment: thanks for link. look like solutions should work from link.

Comment: i also need to know what to write in info.plist  for NSExtensionActivationRule

Comment: look like i need to type all 8 cases or maybe NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount
and 
NSExtensionActivationSupportsText 
will be inaf